My code is causing a triple fault after loading my Global Descriptor Table
My OS is triple faulting when I load my GDT.
I am following these two articles from the osdev wiki:
https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table
https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial
When I load my GDT I get a triple fault. I think it may have to do with this chunk of code:
global loadGDT
loadGDT:
    mov ax, [esp + 4]
    mov [gdtr], ax
    mov eax, [esp + 8]
    mov [gdtr + 2], eax
    lgdt [gdtr]
    ret

global reloadSegments
reloadSegments:
    jmp 0x00:.reload_cs
.reload_cs:
   mov   ax, 0x00
   mov   ds, ax
   mov   es, ax
   mov   fs, ax
   mov   gs, ax
   mov   ss, ax
   ret

If it helps this is what is in my segments:
Code Segment:
Base: 0
Limit: 0xFFFFF
Access Byte: 10011011
Flags: 1000
Data Segment:
Base: 0
Limit: 0xFFFFF
Access Byte: 10010011
Flags: 1000
The reason I changed the 0x08 and 0x10 is because that didn't work either so I changed it to 0 since the base of both my segments is 0.
EDIT:
#include <gdt.h>

uint64_t GDTEntryToInt(SegmentDescriptor descriptor){
    uint64_t rv = 0;
    rv = rv | ((descriptor.limit & 0xFFFF) << 0);
    rv = rv | ((descriptor.base & 0xFFFFF) << 16);
    rv = rv | ((descriptor.accessByte & 0xFF) << 40);
    rv = rv | ((descriptor.limit & 0xF0000) << 48);
    rv = rv | ((descriptor.flags & 0xF) << 52);
    rv = rv | ((descriptor.base & 0xFF0000) << 56);
}


void GDT_Load(){
    gdt[0] = 0;
    SegmentDescriptor codeDescriptor;
    codeDescriptor.base = 0;
    codeDescriptor.limit = 0xFFFFF;
    codeDescriptor.accessByte = GDT_PRESENT | GDT_RING_KERNEL | GDT_DATA_OR_CODE_SEGMENT | GDT_CODE_SEGMENT | GDT_CODE_ONLY_RING_SET | GDT_CODE_READABLE | GDT_ACCESSED;
    codeDescriptor.flags = GDT_GRANULARITY | GDT_16BIT_PROTECTED_SEGMENT;
    SegmentDescriptor dataDescriptor;
    dataDescriptor.base = 0;
    dataDescriptor.limit = 0xFFFFF;
    dataDescriptor.accessByte = GDT_PRESENT | GDT_RING_KERNEL | GDT_DATA_OR_CODE_SEGMENT | GDT_DATA_SEGMENT | GDT_DATA_GROW_UP | GDT_DATA_WRITEABLE | GDT_ACCESSED;
    dataDescriptor.flags = GDT_GRANULARITY | GDT_16BIT_PROTECTED_SEGMENT;
    gdt[1] = GDTEntryToInt(codeDescriptor);
    gdt[2] = GDTEntryToInt(codeDescriptor);
    g_GDTR.offset = (uint32_t)gdt;
    g_GDTR.size = sizeof(gdt) - 1;
    loadGDT(g_GDTR.size, g_GDTR.offset);
    reloadSegments();
}

GITHUB LINK: https://github.com/bessieTheBoy/smallsos

Well if your code selector is 0x08 and your data selector is 0x10 then jmp 0x00:.reload_cs needs to be jmp 0x08:.reload_cs and mov   ax, 0x00 needs to be mov   ax, 0x10 . I assume you are passing an appropriate limit, base to loadDT and then  call reloadSegments . It is possible there is something outside what you are showing causing issues. Without a [mcve] this may be hard to trouble shoot.

Added an edit to include this Michael Petch

Also I don't know what my code or data selector is

If you showed us your GDT that would help. I'd actually recommend using BOCHS to debug this. You can dump out your GDT, look at all the registers, segment registers etc.

I dont know if you mean something else but I showed my gdt right here:
Code Segment:
Base: 0
Limit: 0xFFFFF
Access Byte: 10011011
Flags: 1000
Data Segment:
Base: 0
Limit: 0xFFFFF
Access Byte: 10010011
Flags: 1000
Also I can't use bochs since I don't have my own bootloader and setting up something like grub on bochs would be difficult. I do agree that bochs debugging is going to help a lot with this issue.

Well that's what you say is in your GDT but you don't mention a null descriptor or what order the Code and data segment appeared. For all I know the GDT itself was built incorrectly. Why not just show all the code you use to build your GDT.

Added an edit for this.

If you are using GRUB, then use QEMU and GDB to debug. . Note: Setting up GRUB on BOCHS is quite easy if you use grub-mkrescue to generate an ISO image and then you boot as CD-ROM.

gdt[2] = GDTEntryToInt(codeDescriptor); looks wrong. I think you meant to use gdt[2] = GDTEntryToInt(dataDescriptor); . This could also explain why you get a triple fault. As well as making the change I suggested above about the selectors to use for the JMP (0x08) and MOV (0x10).

I also just noticed that GDTEntryToInt doesn't do a return rv;

Still the same issue after fixing that stuff

If you are in 32-bit protected mode why are you setting the DB bit (in Flags) to a 16-bit segment rather than a 32-bit one? Why not a Flag set to 1100 ( binary ) rather than 1000 ( binary )?

Still triple faulting. Also just looking at the comments that you made I don't think I can use grub-mkrescue since I am on windows. Also I have no idea how to debug with gdb and qemu

Without an [mcve] the problem could well be beyond any code you show here. If you put your code on Github along with commands you use to build or a Makefile I could take a look. I'd recommend using WSL2 on Windows and load a Linux distro - that makes OS development a lot easier.

Added the github link and opened an issue there just in case anyone else sees my github page.

First thing is that because you declared the variables GDTR g_GDTR; uint64_t *gdt; inside gdt.h and you included them in 2 different files you get multiple definition errors. I removed both those lines from gdt.h and put them in gdt.c . I then noticed that you said gdt was a pointer with uint64_t *gdt; but you never initialize that pointer to anything. Instead replace uint64_t *gdt; with uint64_t gdt[3]; which declares an array of 3 uint64_t. I picked 3 because you currently need the NULL selector as the first entry, the codedescriptor as the second and datadescriptor as the third.
